# Covariance with transformations of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm not sure I know where to begin this problem.  We've never worked with covariance but this showed up on some old exams.

Let $X=Y-Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are nonnegative random variables such that $YZ=0$.  Show that $\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z)\leq 0.$

Comment: Does $YZ=0$ mean that $Y*Z$ is a (not so) random variable that takes $0$ with probability $1$? If so: $cov(Y,Z) = E(ZY) - E(Z)E(Y) = 0 - E(Z)E(Y)$... You don't need any information about $X$

Comment: You say "Let $X=Y-Z$", but then you never mention $X$ later in the question.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: $X$ is mentioned in later parts of the question.  For example, part 2 is show $var(X)\geq var(y) + var (z)$

Comment: I get this as long as the fact that YZ=0 means what is said above.  Now I'm attempting part 2

Answer (score 1):

$YZ = 0 \implies \mathbb{E}(YZ)= 0$.

$\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z) = \mathbb{E}(YZ) - \mathbb{E}(Y) \mathbb{E}(Z) = \,...?$